# How get the users's information (account_id) by google email through google api library (e.g. people api) or REST with service account credentials?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

**Hello, Google community**.
I have questions about usage google libraries.

- Could I get information about the user, and if yes - what kind of information and how?
- How can I check if the email address belongs to the group or individual (personal) user. I give you one example of how I want to use this. I want to give some user permissions to my dataset on BigQuery, but I don't know if this individual or group accounts. So, if I gave it to the group account, all users in that specific group would have access to my data. It's exactly not what I want to receive.
- How to check if Google accounts that I receive are without mailbox (Gmail is disabled).
- Is this exactly gmail exists (is this correct email address)?

I'm trying to use a People API library to check use, but I can't get account_id.
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

I found some related StackOverflow questions, but no one gives an answer to my question. So if you could provide some information about that. Or give some clarifications. List of them:

1. how get account_id - github issue -> https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1115
2. [How do I get the Google user ID from an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480833/how-do-i-get-the-google-user-id-from-an-email-address)
3. [Google account ID by account email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279442/google-account-id-by-account-email) - question haven't yet responded.
4. [Google API to retrieve account-id by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366628/google-api-to-retrieve-account-id-by-email)
   [How to get Google User ID using the GMail address in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994610/how-to-get-google-user-id-using-the-gmail-address-in-android)

Comment: Hello! You are asking several questions, I'd suggest you to edit your question in order to focus on a single specific issue. Also, do you have a Workspace account? Are you a domain admin? Are users for which you want to retrieve information part of your domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at GSuite Admin SDK? Using

**User Exists?**

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Checkout retrieve user and the response. It should give you what you are looking for.

**Is it mailing list?**

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups

Comment: It only for enterprise usage, to be more clear it is only for accounts that have G Suite. But we have accounts that have disabled Gmail and GSuite services.

Comment: In that case GSuite Admin SDK is all you need to manage this.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you didn't catch my point of view. We receive accounts which have disabled/enabled GSuite and Gmail services. It can be an all 5 types of google's accounts: Google Account, Service account, Google group, GSuite domain, Cloud Identity domain. But thank you for your answer, I will try this.